# Sending an array with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use Uploadifive and have modified a couple of things.

I made a form where people can select and input values as well as allowing people
to select multiple numbers, like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checker_tiny" name="lid[]" value="1" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="checker_tiny" name="lid[]" value="2" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="checker_tiny" name="lid[]" value="3" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="checker_tiny" name="lid[]" value="4" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="checker_tiny" name="lid[]" value="5" />
```

I now want the form to be send to `/upload/uploadifive.php`

I have tried this by the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // Initialiseer uploadifive
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'              : false,
        'checkScript'       : '/uploadifive/Sample/check-exists.php',
        'onFallback'        : function () {
                                  window.location = '/home.php';
                              },
        'method'            : 'post',
        'queueID'           : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'      : '/upload/uploadifive.php',
        'onUploadComplete'  : function (file, data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                              }
    });

    // Hang een click-event aan de knop
    $('#subby').on('click', function () {
        // Werk formData van uploadifive bij met de betreffende waarden
        $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {
            'timestamp'   : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'       : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
            'projectnr'   : $('input[name=projectnr]').val(),
            'gebruiker'   : $('input[name=gebruiker]').val(),
            'gebruikerid' : $('input[name=userId]').val(),
            'mapId'       : $( "#mapId option:selected" ).val(), // moet dit niet val() zijn???
            'uploadbash'  : '<?php echo $uploadbash; ?>',
            'upload_reden' : $( "#upload_reden option:selected" ).val(),
            'todo'        : $("input[name=todo]:checked").val(),
            'lid'         : $('input[name=lid[]]:checked').val()
        };
        // Voer de upload uit
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

At the moment all the data is being sent and it works, but only the multiple number checkboxes don't send the data correctly.

I get "undefined" on `/upload/uploadifive.php`

What is wrong?

Comment: side note: It's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id. It will make problems for you in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two fixes. First, as in Rajaprabhu Aravindasam's answer, you need to escape the special characters in the name. Second, you need to iterate over all the `lid[]` elements and add them separately into the `formData` object.

```
var formData = {
    'timestamp'   : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
    'token'       : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
    'projectnr'   : $('input[name=projectnr]').val(),
    'gebruiker'   : $('input[name=gebruiker]').val(),
    'gebruikerid' : $('input[name=userId]').val(),
    'mapId'       : $( "#mapId option:selected" ).val(), // moet dit niet val() zijn???
    'uploadbash'  : '<?php echo $uploadbash; ?>',
    'upload_reden' : $( "#upload_reden option:selected" ).val(),
    'todo'        : $("input[name=todo]:checked").val(),
};
$('input[name="lid[]"]:checked').each(function(i) {
    formData['lid['+i+']'] = $(this).val();
});
$('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = formData;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but i get this as a result when i check 2 numbers:

lid%5B%5D=13647&lid%5B%5D=13649 

It are the right numbers, but i preffer to get them back as: 13647, 13649

Seperated with a comma, no other things. Is this possible?

Comment: I was worried that might happen. `serialize()` uses URL-encoding, which is appropriate for URL query parameters and `x-www-form-urlencoded` POST data. But `FormData` is `multipart/form-data`, and this needs each array element to be put into a different parameter, not combined like this.

Comment: Well, i now fixed this problem with str_replace in PHP.
So thank you for the help!

Comment: I updated the answer with something I think will work automatically.

Comment: Another solution would be to `join` all the checkbox values in Javascript, and the `explode` them in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Because it contains two `meta characters` in it. Just escape it like below,

```
$('input[name=lid\\[\\]]:checked').val()
```

or

```
$('input[name="lid[]"]:checked').val()
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to know more about meta-characters.